# How to adjust time command to measure a program elapsed time

Tags: c, time, benchmark

I'm trying to get the time that my program takes to finish (aka elapsed time) so I'm using the common `time`.

What I get by doing this is 3 measurements: user, system and total. This is fine but I found that the user time that I'm interested in has only two decimal places and I would need more. Is there any way I can get more decimal places out of my time command?

Example: `time ./myCProgram`
Output:  0.17s user 1.21s system 130% cpu 0.187 total

Wished output wanted: 0.17000s user 1.21s system 130% cpu 0.187 total
(or more decimal places)

Comment: Are you using bash's builtin `time`? GNU coreutils `time`? What version of `time`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If all you want is elapsed time, then with zsh or ksh93:

```
$ typeset -F SECONDS=0; sleep 1; print "$SECONDS"
1.0012850761
```

Now, whether that kind of precision makes sense is another matter.

Comment: +1 for questioning whether having finer than ms measurement is really sensible.

Comment: Yes this helped me determine where I wanted to get to! Thanks you!

Answer (score 5):

## Computing *time* in *nanoseconds* under *`GNU/Linux`*, using [bash](/questions/tagged/bash).

**WARNING** This post was rendered obsolet by a new nice method discussed there: [Profiling bash (3 answers)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20855353/1765658)and with full *ready-to-use* [bash](/questions/tagged/bash) source file there: [Elap-bash V3](http://f-hauri.ch/vrac/elap-bash-v3)

### Ways to retrieve reliable values

There are some way to ask for time in a finer granularity than one second.

#### First, but not best: 1/100th of second

For 1/100th of second, you could simply refer to `/proc/uptime`:

```
sed 's/ .*$//' /proc/uptime 
276440.58
```

The *time offset* to add for calculating real UTC time could be obtain by one of:

```
ps ho lstart 1 | date -f - +%s
1357193821
```

or

```
date +%s.%N-$(sed 's/ .*$//' /proc/uptime ) | bc -l
1357193821.088187101
```

As offset are static, this value could be computed only 1 time, at begin of script.

#### 1/1000000000th of seconds, using `proc` entries only:

For computing with **nanoseconds**, there is a `proc entry`, named `/proc/timer_list` which contain both `uptime` and `offset`:

```
sed < /proc/timer_list -ne '/now at/p;/offset/{p;q}'
now at 276350507668586 nsecs
  .offset:     1357193821075753443 nsecs
```

So this

```
echo $(($(sed < /proc/timer_list -ne '
    /^now at/{s/now at \([0-9]*\) ns.*$/\1/;H};
    /offset/{s/^.*: *\([0-9]*\) ns.*$/\1/;G;s/\n\+/+/;p;q}'))) 
1357470173543424035
```

is the **integer** number of **nanoseconds** elapsed from `1970-1-1 00:00:00 UTC`.

For computing integer under [bash](/questions/tagged/bash), there is no need to use `bc` and for parsing proc files, we could use `mapfile` which is a *bash builtin*:

```
# first, some static variables (with fork, but only 1 time, at begin;):
nowAtLine=$(($(sed -ne < /proc/timer_list '/now at/{=;q}')-1))
offset=$(sed -ne < /proc/timer_list '
    /offset/{s/^.*: *\([0-9]*\) n.*$/\1/p;q}')

# than this will be a lot quicker than a fork:
mapfile -n 1 -s $nowAtLine timerList </proc/timer_list &&
    timerList=($timerList) &&
    echo $((${timerList[2]}+offset))
1357470173543424035
```

#### 1/1000000000th of seconds, using `date` binary tool:

And finaly if they not exist, we could call `date` keeping in mind that it's a `fork` wich take a lot more time than reading `proc files`, staying in only one bash session.

```
date +%s%N
1357470074808968375
```

### My `elap.bash` function

based on this, I wrote a [elap bash function](http://www.f-hauri.ch/vrac/cours_truc-et-astuces_2012-04-03/elap.bash), with two counters: 1 for each call and the other for a kind of `overall duration`.

#### Usage:

First, this is a *function*, not a *script*. You have to `source` them in your current bash session in order for using it.

```
. elap.bash
```

Syntaxe:

```
elap [ [ -r | -R ] | [ -n ] [ -t | -T ] [<simple text report>] ]
    -r reset first counter only, don't output anything, like -R...
    -R reset both counters, (both -r and -R must by unique argument)
    -n don't reset any counter (just print)
    -t print both counters (reset first counter)
    -T print and reset
```

Than reset both counters before using it:

```
elap -R
find /usr/bin >/dev/null
elap browsing /usr/bin

     0.025389543 browsing /usr/bin
```

So you could add some markers in a script:

```
#!/bin/bash
. elap.bash
  elap -R
tar -cf /tmp/test.tar -C / bin
  elap making a tarball of $(stat -c %s /tmp/test.tar) bytes
gzip /tmp/test.tar
  elap compressing them to $(stat -c %s /tmp/test.tar.gz) bytes
scp /tmp/test.tar.gz backup@elswhere.net:backups/
  elap sending file to backup server
rm /tmp/test.tar.gz
  elap removing compressed tarball
elap -t total duration

     0.043223957 making a tarball of 5877760 bytes
     0.667249628 compressing them to 2742537 bytes
test.tar.gz                                  100% 2678KB 2.6MB/s 00:00
     0.380779818 sending file to backup server
     0.010262259 removing compressed tarball
     0.003566335      1.105081997 total duration
```

#### Using `trap debug` for following *step-by-step*

With or without the `-t` switch, using `trap debug` for step by step, wit less script alteration (added four lines at top of script and one at bottom):

As trapping for *debug* will occure **before** `$BASH_COMMAND` execution, we need to store variable content to a `$BASH_LAST` variable for correct printing, and add a *dummy* command at bottom of script.

```
#!/bin/bash

. elap.bash
elap -R
export BASH_LAST=Starting
trap 'elap -t $BASH_LAST;BASH_LAST=$BASH_COMMAND' debug 

tar -cf /tmp/test.tar -C / bin
gzip /tmp/test.tar
scp /tmp/test.tar.gz backup@elswhere.net:backups/
rm /tmp/test.tar.gz

exit $?
```

The `exit $?` command is needed to dump statistiques **after** the last `rm` command.

```
     0.001011086      0.001011086 Starting
     0.045175969      0.046187055 tar -cf /tmp/test.tar -C / bin
     0.651394209      0.697581264 gzip /tmp/test.tar
test.tar.gz                                  100% 2678KB 2.6MB/s 00:00
     0.374499354      1.072080618 scp /tmp/test.tar.gz backup@elswhere.net:backups/
     0.007160101      1.079240719 rm /tmp/test.tar.gz
```

#### The function source

Where you could cut (or reorder) `uptime` part, if you prefer using fork to `date +%s%N` instead of using 1/100th of seconds granularity.

```
#
# Bash source file for fine elapsed time reporting
# based on /proc/timer_list, display elapsed time in nanosecs
# or /proc/uptime if timer_list not present, for 100th of secs.
# if none of them if present, fall back to *fork* `date +%s%N`.
#
# (C) 2011-2012 Felix Hauri - felix@f-hauri.ch
# Licensed under terms of LGPL v3. www.gnu.org

# Usage:
#   load script into bash using ``source elap.bash''
#
# Syntaxe: elap [ [ -r | -R ] | [ -n ] [ -t | -T ] [<simple text report>] ]
#   -r reset first counter only, don't output anything, like -R...
#   -R reset both counters, (both -r and -R must by unique argument)
#   -n don't reset any counter (just print)
#   -t print both counters (reset first counter)
#   -T print and reset
#
# nota: using ``-n'' in combinaison with any of ``-r'' or ``-R'' is buggy.

export _elaP_now _elaP_last _elaP_elap _elaP_last2 _elaP_dec

if [ -r /proc/timer_list ] ;then
    _elaP_file=/proc/timer_list
    _elaP_dec=9
    _elaP_field=2
    mapfile < $_elaP_file _elaP_now
    _elaP_line=0
    while [ "${_elaP_now[_elaP_line]}" == \
    "${_elaP_now[_elaP_line]#*now at}" ] ;do
    ((_elaP_line++))
    done
    eval 'function elap_getNow() {
     mapfile -n 1 -s '$_elaP_line' <'$_elaP_file' _elaP_now
         _elaP_now=($_elaP_now)
         _elaP_now=${_elaP_now[_elaP_field]}
         }'
else
    #      --- To be removed for nanoseconds only
    if [ -r /proc/uptime ] ;then
    _elaP_dec=2
    function elap_getNow() {
        read -a _elaP_now </proc/uptime _elaP_now
            _elaP_now=${_elaP_now//./}
    }
    else # --- End of part to be removed for ns only.
    _elaP_dec=9
    function elap_getNow() { _elaP_now=$(date +%s%N) ;}
    fi   # --- Remove this line too for ns only.
fi

export -f elap_getNow

elap() {
    local _Z9=000000000
    local _elaP_setLast=true
    [ "$1" == "-n" ] && shift && _elaP_setLast=false
    [ "$2" == "-n" ] && set -- $1 ${@:3} && _elaP_setLast=false

    elap_getNow

    _elaP_elap=$((_elaP_now - _elaP_last))
    [ ${#_elaP_elap} -lt $_elaP_dec ] && \
    _elaP_elap=${_Z9:0:_elaP_dec-${#_elaP_elap}}$_elaP_elap
    [ "${*}" == "-R" ] &&  _elaP_last2=$_elaP_now || \
    [ "${*}" == "-r" ] || if [ "$1" == "-t" ] || [ "$1" == "-T" ] ;then
    local _elaP_setLast2=false
    [ "$1" == "-T" ] && _elaP_setLast2=true
    shift
            _elaP_elap2=$((_elaP_now - _elaP_last2))
    [ ${#_elaP_elap2} -lt $_elaP_dec ] && \
        _elaP_elap2="${_Z9:0:_elaP_dec-${#_elaP_elap2}}$_elaP_elap2"
        printf "%6d.%s %6d.%s %s\n" \
        "${_elaP_elap:0:${#_elaP_elap}-$_elaP_dec}" \
        "${_elaP_elap:${#_elaP_elap}-_elaP_dec}" \
        "${_elaP_elap2:0:${#_elaP_elap2}-$_elaP_dec}" \
        "${_elaP_elap2:${#_elaP_elap2}-_elaP_dec}"      "${*}"
    $_elaP_setLast2 && _elaP_last2=$_elaP_now
    else
        printf "%6d.%s %s\n" \
        "${_elaP_elap:0:${#_elaP_elap}-$_elaP_dec}" \
        "${_elaP_elap:${#_elaP_elap}-_elaP_dec}"        "${*}"
    fi
    $_elaP_setLast && _elaP_last=$_elaP_now
}

export -f elap
```

Comment: Further work around this at [Stack Overflow - How to profile a bash shell script](http://stackoverflow.com/a/20855353/1765658)

Comment: And [How to manipulate timing and typescript files created by "script" command?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71009297/1765658)