# How to get SCP execution time in milliseconds?

Tags: linux, command, timestamps

I have a script in which i am reading source and destination IP address from a csv file and recording the time in milliseconds it is taking to copy the file from source to destination (using scp).
Below is my script.

```
#!/bin/bash
while IFS="," read f1 f2
do
        echo "Source IP        : $f1"       
        echo "Destination IP   : $f2"
export sourceIP=$f1
export destIP=$(echo "$f2" | tr -d '\n')
ssh -t -t sjain@$f1 'bash -s' <<ENDSSH
#Start copying 100MB File
startTime=$(($(date '+%s%N')/1000000))
echo \$startTime
scp MB_100.txt sjain@$destIP:/home/sjain
endTime=$(($(date '+%s%N')/1000000))
echo \$endTime
printf 'Elapsed time in copying 33KB file: %s\n' \$((endTime-startTime)) 
#Write the stats to the file
echo $sourceIP','$destIP',33KB,'\$((endTime-startTime)) >> report.txt
exit
ENDSSH

#Write the stats to the file
#echo '10.234.0.9,10.234.0.19,33KB,'\$((endTime-startTime)) >> report.txt

done < ipaddress.csv
```

**Output**

```
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ #Start copying 100MB File
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ startTime=1394659673854
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ echo $startTime
1394659673854
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ scp MB_100.txt sjain@10.X.X.X:/home/sjain
MB_100.txt                                    100%  100MB 100.0MB/s   00:00
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ endTime=1394659673855
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ echo $endTime
1394659673855
ndTime-startTime)) D01 ~]$ printf 'Elapsed time in copying 33KB file: %s\n' $((e
Elapsed time in copying 33KB file: 1
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ #Write the stats to the file
Time)) >> report.txt01 ~]$ echo 10.Y.Y.Y','10.X.X.X',33KB,'$((endTime-start
[sjain@XYZ ~]$ exit
exit
Connection to 10.Y.Y.Y closed.
```

The problem that I am facing right now , it is not returning me the time in milliseconds (i think) , it is giving in seconds.

Please help in fixing this issue.

Comment: Look at this [answer](http://unix.stackexchange.com/a/60434/27653)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'd better use `time`.

For example

```
TMP=$(mktemp)
time (scp yourfile user@otherhost:/path/ ) 2>$TMP
awk -F'[ ms]+' '/^real/ {print "copy time: "1000*$2"ms"}' $TMP
rm $TMP
```

Comment: i think in `COPYTIME` expression , 1 single quote is missing.
i am getting this error
`./dummy.sh: command substitution: line 57: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `''
./dummy.sh: command substitution: line 59: syntax error: unexpected end of file`

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `scp` in verbose mode and grab the timing stats. Replace your `scp` line as follows:

```
scp -v src dest 2>&1 | grep 'Transferred' | awk '{print $(NF - 1) * 1000}'
```

Edit: This might not be precise to the millisecond.

With python, one can get microsecond level precision, eg.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import subprocess
import datetime

a=datetime.datetime.now()
subprocess.call(["scp", "-r", "a-dir/", "username@machine.name:~/"])
b=datetime.datetime.now()
print (b-a).microseconds
```

Comment: What OS is this on? My `scp` (Debian) does not print this info.

Comment: @terdon this is BSD scp on Ubuntu "precise 12.04.xx".

Comment: Never mind, I was doing something stupid. It does indeed print this on my Debian.

Comment: @ketan is there anyway to make it precise ?

Comment: @tech-idiot This can be done with python if that is acceptable to you. See my updates on answer.